# Overscroll handling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a Pull-to-Refresh logic in my app.

I know it starts with handling Overscrolling, but I can't seem to find anything in compose that has to do with Overscrolling.

Is it not implemented in Compose yet? Or is it hidden somewhere?

I'm using a LazyColumn right now, I didn't find anything in the LazyListState.

Comment: I built a [library](https://github.com/fengdai/compose-pulltorefresh/) as an alternative to **SwipeRefresh** which provides the classic pull-to-refresh pattern. Check it out if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Swipe Refresh feature included in Google's [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist) library.

Example usage:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()

SwipeRefresh(
    state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing),
    onRefresh = { viewModel.refresh() },
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(30) { index ->
            // TODO: list items
        }
    }
}
```

See the [docs](https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/) for more details.

Comment: Swipe gesture doesn't work