# There is something similar like swiperefreshlayout to pull to refresh in the LazyColumn jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

There is something similar like swiperefreshlayout to pull to refresh in the jetpack compose

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65611827/4136777

Comment: @DuncanLukkenaer, that solution is outdated now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Google's Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/swiperefresh) is now **deprecated**. Official support is now available in Compose Material from versin 1.3.0 use following code:

The lines I marked with **1**, **2**, **3** does the job:

```
val ptrState= 
   rememberPullRefreshState(viewState.isRefreshing, {viewModel.pullToRefresh()}) // 1

Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .pullRefresh(ptrState)) { // 2
    LazyColumn(state = rememberLazyListState()) {
        items(
            items = viewState.YOUR_LIST_ITEMS,
            key = { item -> item.id },
            itemContent = {
                YourItemCompose(it)
            })
    }
    PullRefreshIndicator
          (viewState.isRefreshing, ptrState, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)) // 3
}
```

`viewState.isRefreshing` is a boolean holding your refresh state and `viewModel.pullToRefresh()` is the method to do the actual work for refreshing the data (e.g. calling the API again)

in case you don't know the dependency:

```
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
```

Comment: While it works, `viewState.isRefreshing` is not changing and it's value is not used.

Answer (score 45):

**Edit:**
Google Accompanist's swipe refresh is deprecated with official pull refresh support in [androidx.compose.material.pullrefresh](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/pullrefresh/package-summary)

Sample usage:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
val refreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing

val pullRefreshState = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, { viewModel.refresh() })

Box(Modifier.pullRefresh(pullRefreshState)) {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        ...
    }

    PullRefreshIndicator(refreshing, pullRefreshState, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
}
```

**Original Answer:**

You can use [Google's Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/swiperefresh) library for implementing swipe-to-refresh.

Sample usage:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
val isRefreshing by viewModel.isRefreshing.collectAsState()

SwipeRefresh(
    state = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing),
    onRefresh = { viewModel.refresh() },
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(30) { index ->
            // TODO: list items
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://google.github.io/accompanist/swiperefresh/

Comment: Swipe to refresh is deprecated in Accompanist and is now available in Compose Material: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/pullrefresh/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pullRefresh(androidx.compose.material.pullrefresh.PullRefreshState,kotlin.Boolean)

Answer (score 26):

Starting with **M2** `1.3.0-beta03` there is a new built-in Pull-To-Refresh component, with the [**`pullRefresh`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/pullrefresh/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pullRefresh(androidx.compose.material.pullrefresh.PullRefreshState,kotlin.Boolean)) modifier.

You can use something like:

```
val refreshScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var refreshing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var itemCount by remember { mutableStateOf(15) }

fun refresh() = refreshScope.launch {
    refreshing = true
    delay(1500)
    itemCount += 5
    refreshing = false
}

val state = rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, ::refresh)

//pullRefresh modifier
Box(Modifier.pullRefresh(state)) {

    //vertically scrollable content
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        if (!refreshing) {
            items(itemCount) {
                ListItem { Text(text = "Item ${itemCount - it}") }
            }
        }
    }

    //standard Pull-Refresh indicator. You can also use a custom indicator 
    PullRefreshIndicator(refreshing, state, Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
}
```

[image]

**Note:** currently, the content of the Composable with the `pullRefresh` modifier **needs to be 'vertically scrollable'** to be able to react to swipe gestures. Layouts such as `LazyColumn` are automatically vertically scrollable, in the other cases you can provide a **`verticalScroll`** modifier to that content.

Something like:

```
//pullRefresh modifier
Box( Modifier.pullRefresh(state) ) {

    //vertically scrollable content
    Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        // content
    }

    //PullRefreshIndicator
}
```

Comment: Is there a built-in Pull-To-Refresh component for Material3?

Comment: @adek111 Not currently

Comment: why can i only use this with LazyColumn? it doesen't work with fullscreen box or colymn neither

Comment: @DaniilPozdnyakov I've updated the answer. You have to use a **vertically scrollable** content, not necessarily a `LazyColumn` to use the `pullRefresh` modifier.