# Manually refresh paging data in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging, android-paging-3

I'm using paging-compose library to load  paginated data from server using remote mediator (backed by local room database). Is there any way to manually refresh mediator data in case of swipe to refresh?

Answer (score 9):

Calling `refresh()` method on `LazyPagingItems` should work for swipe to refresh (UI driven event) as mention in [documentation **`LazyPagingItems.refresh()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems#refresh())

> Refresh the data presented by this `LazyPagingItems`.

> `refresh` triggers the creation of a new `PagingData` with a new instance of `PagingSource` to represent an updated snapshot of the backing dataset. If a `RemoteMediator` is set, calling refresh will also trigger a call to `RemoteMediator.load` with **REFRESH** to allow `RemoteMediator` to check for updates to the dataset backing `PagingSource`.

> Note: This API is intended for ***UI-driven refresh signals***, such as ***swipe-to-refresh***

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204979/there-is-something-similar-like-swiperefreshlayout-to-pull-to-refresh-in-the-laz for pull to refresh behaviour.